# Can I combine 2 levels of counts in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

may data is like:

```
user    RO  retweetID
jim     o   (null)
jim     o   (null)
jim     r   r8
bill    o   (null)
bill    r   r3
fred    o   (null)
fred    r   r6
fred    r   r6
fred    r   r1
```

I want to count o's, r's and avgercount (total number of r's/number of different r's)
so I should get:

```
user        ocount rcount avgercount
jim         2      1      1
bill        1      1      1
fred        1      3      1.5
```

I'm stuck at the beggining, on [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5c082/2). Any help much appreciated.

EDIt: to clarify:
avgercount =  (total number of r's/number of different r's)
that is for Fred, he has three retweets: r6, r6, r1 but only two of them are different, avgercount = 3/2.

Comment: And how is `avgercount` calculated?  This is not obvious.

Comment: I have tried to clarify it with an edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation to get the base counts:

```
select user,
       sum(case when ro = 'o' then 1 else 0 end) as o_cnt,
       sum(case when ro = 'r' then 1 else 0 end) as r_cnt,
       avg(case when ro = 'r' then 1.0 else 0.0 end) as avg_r,
       sum(case when ro = 'r' then 1.0 else 0 end) / count(distinct case when ro = 'r' then retweetID end) as retweet_ratio
from t
group by user;
```

This calculates for the average value of "r".  It is unclear what your calculation is in the question.

In MySQL, this can be shortened to:

```
select user,
       sum( ro = 'o' ) as o_cnt,
       sum( ro = 'r' ) as r_cnt,
       sum( ro = 'r' ) / count(distinct case when ro = 'r' then retweetID end) as retweetid_ratio
from t
group by user;
```

Comment: Wow, I like the shortened version in MySQL. I learn everyday from you sir.

Comment: Boolean expressions like `ro = 'o'` get treated as *true* or *false* in `WHERE` clauses, and like `1` or `0` where they're expected to be numbers.  This neat trick is MySQL specific.